# Taylor expansion of operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

This is all in the context of the Ising model and the renormalization group; but this question is (I believe) self-consistent and is just a matter of operator-juggling.

I have an operator $\Delta^{-1}(-i\nabla)$ defined as $\Delta^{-1}(p)$ with $p$ replaced by derivative operators $-i\nabla$.

I know that:
\begin{equation}
\Delta^{-1}(p) = \frac{4DT}{T_C\sum_{a=1}^D \left[2\cos p_a + 2 \right]}
\end{equation}

It is apparently "easy" to show, by a Taylor expansion of the operator above that:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\phi(x)\Delta^{-1}(-i\nabla)\phi(x) = \frac{T}{T_C}\frac{\phi^2(x)}{2} + \frac{T}{4DT_C}\frac{\left(\nabla\phi(x)\right)^2}{2}+...
\end{equation}

I can see where the first term comes from, as $\Delta^{-1}(0) = T/T_C$. But how can I get the second term? How to I get the Taylor series? I am a bit confused because I have a function of the components of $p$ instead of $p$ itself.

**EDIT**

Following the comments below:
\begin{equation}
2\cos p_a + 2 \sim 4 - p_a^2
\end{equation}

Then:
\begin{equation}
\Delta^{-1}(p) \sim \frac{T}{T_C}\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4D}\sum_{a=1}^Dp_a^2}\right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\Delta^{-1}(p) \sim \frac{T}{T_C}\left( 1 + \frac{1}{4D}\sum_{a=1}^D p_a^2\right)
\end{equation}

Substituting $p \to -i\nabla$

\begin{equation}
\Delta ^{-1}(p) \sim \frac{T}{T_C} - \frac{T}{4DT_C}\nabla^2
\end{equation}

Which is still different to the expression required.

Comment: First expand your operator  to second order in $\vec p$, a parameter. What is it you get?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I don't know how to do that. I don't know how to expand that expression in powers of $p$.

Comment: Go step by step. Start with the denominator. Can you expand $\cos p_a$ to second order in $p_a$? If you can do that, can you expand $\sum_{a=1}^D (2+2 \cos p_a)$ to second order in $p_a$ (expand cosine to second order, then do the sum on $a$)? If you can do those steps, you're most of the way there; the last piece you need is that $1/(1+\epsilon) = 1 - \epsilon$ for small $\epsilon$.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks. I got a bit closer with your suggestions; but I still don't get the correct expression. Could you give it a look once you have some time? I added my attempt as an edit.

Comment: I think  the last step is that $\phi \nabla^2 \phi = - (\nabla \phi)^2$ after integrating by parts and dropping a boundary term. With that it looks to me like you have the right expression.

Comment: $\phi\nabla^2\phi=\nabla\cdot (\phi \nabla \phi) - (\nabla\phi)^2$. Is your context allowing you to dismiss the first term?